# Link in page that open a hidden div in another page JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I searched and tried a lot of examples but i couldnt figure it out

My problem is that i want to click a link (for example the second one) in my index that redirect to another page and also open a hidden div.
I was trying comparing the hash and adding differents events but it didn't work.

Index.html

```
<div> 
   <ul>
       <li><a href="services.html#page1">link-1</a></li>
       <li><a href="services.html#page2">link-2</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Services.html

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="nav">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li id="link"><a href="#" data-page="page1"></a></li>
            <li id="link"><a href="#" data-page="page2"></a></li>
        </ul>
   </div>

  <div class="main">
    <div id="page1" class="content"> 
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 1
    </div>

    <div id="page2" class="content"> 
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

style.css

```
.content { display:none; }
```

(I try with visibility: hidden too)

document.Js

```
 $(function() {
            var curPage="";

              if(!curPage){
              $('#page1').show()
            curPage = "page1"
          }
            $("#menu a").click(function() {
                if (curPage.length) { 
                    $("#"+curPage).hide();
                }
                curPage=$(this).data("page");
                $("#"+curPage).show();
            });     
        });
```

The last I did was compare the hash to div in second page and add a 'show' class or compare the hash and if its "page2" click on the nav but they didnt work

```
if(window.location.hash) {
      var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    /*i tried a lot here */
  } else {
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be confusing the URL anchor location (i.e. `services.html#page1`) with the jquery/css id selector (i.e. `$('#page1')`)

The only thing the URL anchor location does is tell the browser that when it loads a page, it needs to find a place with the specified anchor name and scroll to it. You can use it to accomplish what you are attempting, but you have to modify your javascript so that it grabs the anchor location (try `location.hash` in the javascript) so that you can see if you are supposed to show page1 or page2.

It looks like your javascript function is using the JQuery selector properly. (`$('#page1')` will give you a reference to the div with `id="page1"`) but the first thing it should do is grab the url location, then set curPage to `page1` or `page2` appropriately. Then, if it is `page1` do a  `$('#page1').show() and  $('#page2').hide()` (or vice versa if it is `page2`)

Answer (score 0):

is it after the redirect is done that you want to show the hidden div or before redirect??

Comment: This isn't an answer, post it as a comment on the original post

Comment: Oh, looks like you need 50 rep to post comments.

Comment: ook...just knowing this also